# DockPanel Suite child form events not firing

Tags: .net, winforms, events, visual-c++, dockpanel-suite

I'm using [WeifenLuo Dockpanel Suite](https://github.com/dockpanelsuite/dockpanelsuite) in winforms.
i have 2 forms (Main & child form), Main form has dockpanel & child form will be docked in this dockpanel.
in child form, none of the events are firing except DockChanged & DockStateChanged

```
private: Void CamWindow_ResizeBegin(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
  Console::WriteLine("Resize begin"); //doesn't work, tried many other mouse events as well
}   

private: Void CamWindow_DockStateChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
  Console::WriteLine("Dock state Changed");  //works   
}
```

i don't think this is bug, how to make these events fire?

Answer (score 0):

Probably a bug, you can find more information on [Dock panel dockchanged event don't trigger](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/DQ43775)

Comment: in the link Stan said "_you can manage this process by handling the DockManager's EndDocking event_"    can you elaborate this a bit? Thanks

Comment: @PrakashM you may find more information in https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q367571 link. I will elaborate more if required.

Comment: Interesting that you linked a DevExpress component while the question is about an open sourced project.